# Why can't a Managed Metadata field be sealed?

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, list-definition

I am creating a custom list definition that contains Managed Metadata fields ([TaxonomyFieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.aspx)). These taxonomy fields are !important so users should not be able to delete them through the UI. I eventually got it to work using AllowDeletion, but I first tried Sealed. But marking the field as Sealed completely broke the column.

As a sanity test, I created a test list definition with the following four fields:

- Taxonomy Test A: Sealed=NULL, AllowDeletion=NULL
- Taxonomy Test B: Sealed=NULL, AllowDeletion=FALSE
- Taxonomy Test C: Sealed=TRUE, AllowDeletion=NULL
- Taxonomy Test D: Sealed=TRUE, AllowDeletion=FALSE

When I deploy the solution, create a list instance, and upload a document, columns A and B work fine, but columns C and D are disabled:

[image: EditForm.aspx showing Managed Metadata fields are disabled when sealed]

As annoying and broken as that is, it gets worse when I go to save:

[image: Failed to get value of the "Taxonomy Test C" column from the "Managed Metadata" field type control. See details in log. Exception message: Invalid field name. {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]

In this case, the requirement was just to prevent the column from being deleted, so AllowDeletion is a suitable workaround. But what if I truly needed the field to be sealed so that a user cannot change the settings for Multiple Values, Display Format, Default Value, or, most importantly, Term Set?

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting the 'ShowInXXXForm' [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452757.aspx) for the field, where XXX is something like the New, Edit, List View, List Settings, etc. pages?

That way, you could simply make them unavailable for deletion, editing, etc., through the UI. The setting that I *think* you'd be interested in is [ShowInListSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinlistsettings.aspx)

Comment: That's a good workaround option to deter users from changing what you don't want changed. But it's kind of the nuclear option as it doesn't let the user change what sealed allows you to change (name, description, order). Also, it doesn't truly lock down the column since it can still be edited through URL spoofing. So, a good workaround, but still leaves the question why sealed doesn't work. Thanks.